# Retrieve data from SQL Server and convert it into JSON using python

Tags: json, sql-server, python-3.x

I'm trying to retrieve data from SQL server database and convert into JSON format using python script but I'm getting some errors.

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
    import json
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=localhost;'
                          'Database=TestDB;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from dbo.test where id = 1 ')
    rs = cursor.fetchall()
    result = dict(rs)
    r = json.dumps(rs)
    for row in r:
         print(r)
```

Error:

> result = dict(rs)
>    ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required

Expected output:

```
"{ "id" : 1, "type": "release",  "consent": true,  "quantity": 5}"
```

Please let me know where I'm wrong in my script.

Comment: @DaleK yes, retrieve. sorry.

Comment: Does your script work if you `fetchone()` instead of `fetchall()`? Fetchall will return a list of tuples, but it is hard to know the form of the tuple since you `select *`